# Applying Spark reduceByKey to generic with context bounds

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm still new to context bounds in Scala and I'm trying to write a function that can perform a reduceByKey on any any generic that satisfies a context bound.
eg

```
def myReduce[K: ClassTag, V: ClassTag: Numeric[V]](in: RDD[(K, V)]): RDD[(K, V)] = {
  in.reduceByKey{case (v1, v2) =>
    implicityly[Numeric[V]].plus(v1, v2)
  }
```

As far as I understand this should work however when trying to compile I get the following errors.

1. error: could not find implicit value for parameter e: Numeric
2. error: Numeric[V] does not take type parameters

These I don't understand.
I'm not passing in type parameters to Numeric[V] anywhere. Also shouldn't the context bound automatically import the 'evidence' for the conversion?

I was hoping to instead to eventually use my own trait instead of Numeric.

Edit:

I tried explicitly writing the implicit evdience in the function as follows:

```
def myReduce[K: ClassTag, V: ClassTag](in: RDD[(K, V)])(implicit ev: V => Numeric[V]): RDD[(K, V)] = {
  in.reduceByKey{case (v1, v2) =>
    implicityly[Numeric[V]].plus(v1, v2)
  }
```

But I still get the "error: could not find implicit value for parameter e: Numeric" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I solved the issue

```
def myReduce[K: ClassTag, V: ClassTag: Numeric](in: RDD[(K, V)]): RDD[(K, V)] = {
  in.reduceByKey{case (v1, v2) =>
    implicityly[Numeric[V]].plus(v1, v2)
  }
```

The issue was specifying Numeric[V] instead of just Numeric.
I've ran into more issues now but that's for another day.